# Why my bubbles particles stop working at frame 11

Tags: particles

I'm working on a fish tank and so I would like to create air bubbles which go up until the surface. I have put 600 frames in the render. And as you can see on the image, I put settings. But my particles die at 11 frames. Do you know the reason? Did I put wrong settings?

thanks for help ;)

[image]

Comment: May i ask if you tried clearing the cache, as in the picture i can't see much more then the basic settings, it's more like guesswork here, more pictures, or maybe even the .blend-file [Blender-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) could help a lot. That said, saving the file with all removed but the particle system and needed parts to reproduce the problem, would be appreciated.

Comment: I was deleting the other objects in order to upload the project with only particles, and when I tried to preview like that, the bubbles don't stop and it works...Is possible that the problem is just I have a too big project?

Comment: I don't think the project was too big, but there might have been some things interfering with the particles. While i'm happy for you that it works now, i would suggest to do the removing procedure once more and test step by step to find when it works. It's always better to know for the future then just being happy that it works. Also, it may help others if you point out what was the problem in an answer you give yourself, as a solved question is always better then an open one, so people don't try to solve your problem long time later not knowing that you found the solution already.

Comment: I've just remarked that the bubbles become smaller at frame 11, that's why I didn't see them : /

Comment: That's either something controlled by the object standing in for the bubbles or is set up in the not visible properties. As i mentioned, it would be a good idea to write an answer pointing out that the particles were getting too small with the reason, as it was something you found out yourself. There are just too many possible reasons, that's why it helps to point out those that lead to the question.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know why the bubbles are getting smaller, and I don't succeed to upload the project : / Could you tell me what properties should I show you? and I'll take screenshots. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104262/discussion-between-xylvier-and-magsu-art).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conversation, i would check out the object that is used for the bubbles, should that be animated and shrink, it would also reduce the particles size.

Below the direct relation between size of the object and the resulting nearly dissapearing particles:

[image: Object used for the particles changing size affects the particles as well]

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to chat with and find the solution to my problem. I made a wrong manipulation when scaling my bubble object and so I put 2 different keyframes without wanting. Thank you!!